# error: "_structName" has already been declared in the current scope

Tags: c

I am running into this "already declared" compilation error when building my program. I know that this can sometimes be caused by including the same header file twice. However, I am using an ifndef preprocessor directive to avoid such a scenario. It seems that this struct must be declared in another header file somewhere else in my build path. Is there any way to figure out where this struct is initially declared?

Comment: Please post the code showing your struct declaration, and relevant output from the compiler that shows the error you are getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(In root of build path)

Linux:

```
find . | xargs grep name_of_your_struct
```

Windows (I am not 100% on the syntax, here, but I believe this is correct. Try `findstr /?` if this doesn't work.)

```
findstr /S "name_of_your_struct"`
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning findstr. You usually don't need the `find` in the Unix case though - grep has a -R flag.

Comment: That's a fair comment, but I've always used find out of habit so that I can invoke it easily on directories which are not my current, without switching directories. If there's an option to do this in grep, then I have been sorely missing out!

Comment: `grep -R "text to search" directory_to_search`
Enjoy!

Comment: Why thank you. It seems a bit to obvious to try this (or even for me to RTFM, :P!), that I managed to miss it for so long.
Many, many thanks.
This may extend my life without carpal tunnel syndrome for years! :P.